# Copy dependency of a maven project to specific folder

Tags: maven, dependencies

I am trying to get all the jar required for a maven project inside a particular folder.

I have used `mvn dependency:copy-dependencies` command.

It gives me the required jar files inside `taget/dependeny` folder.

Although I can use move or copy coommand to copy those jars to another directory, is there any way to copy the dependencies in directory of my choice directly?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to use the [`outputDirectory`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html#outputDirectory) property to define the required location where you would like the jars to be copied to.

Here is an example of the configuration you would add in your POM:

```xml
<plugins>
...
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/alternateLocation</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
    ...
</plugins>
```

Alternatively you can pass this configuration directly via the command line:

```
mvn -DoutputDirectory=alternativeLocation dependency:copy-dependencies
```

Comment: I am aware of output directory thing, I just want to know if it can be done by command only.