# Java ClassNotFoundException (I used scope compile in maven)

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

So, I have a `ClassNotFoundException` from my discord bot whenever I run it outside of Eclipse:

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try 
again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
sx/blah/discord/handle/obj/IChannel
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sx.blah.discord.handle.obj.IChannel
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 7 more
```

This shoud not be happening, as I have scope compile in Maven. I even explicitly put it in scope compile:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.austinv11</groupId>
        <artifactId>Discord4J</artifactId>
        <version>dev-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.16.16</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Maven is a build tool. It compiles and packages your classes. But it doesn't run it. How do you run your code?

Comment: java -cp JarName.jar com.hallowizer.package.Main

Comment: And how did you create your jar?

Comment: So you only put your own jar in the classpath, And not the jar it depends on. Use `java -cp jarname.jar:path/to/Discord4J.jar  com.hallowizer.package.Main` (replace `:` by `;` if you're on Windows).

Comment: To create/copy the dependent JARs in the target folder see https://stackoverflow.com/a/33012995/6505250

Comment: So, is there a simpler way to do this? All I want to do here is to have a dependency in my project, without the user having to download it.

Comment: I think this is what you need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729054/including-dependencies-in-a-jar-with-maven - you will get a "yourproject-version-jar-with-dependencies.jar" in result which will contain every dependency besides your app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Apache Maven** is a build tool for,

- **Retrieving project dependencies** (3rd party Jars, etc.) from remote repositories to the local machine based on the dependencies declared in the *pom.xml* file.
- **Compiling** Java classes

In your case, your *pom.xml* fetched all the dependencies and put them on your local computer. Eclipse's built-in Maven plugin puts those Jar files in your project's *classpath*. This is the reason, you were able to run your application within Eclipse IDE.

If you wish to run your application outside Eclipse IDE, you can do it in a couple of ways:

1. Put all the dependencies (JARs) in your application **classpath**, e.g,

   `$ java -cp ".:./jars/a.jar; ../jars/b.jar" myClass`
2. Create a **uber jar** by using **Maven Shade plugin**. [Here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/index.html) is the documentation on using the Shade plugin.

Comment: Thanks! That was very helpful, I have a working bot now!